# Change current Date without changing a server clock In Java

Tags: java, date

For the effective date support, we need the ability to change the 'current date' to be a future date without changing a server clock in a test environment

give me an ideas to implement this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using some similar mechanism to this to get your current time:

```
GregorianCalendar now = new GregorianCalendar();
```

To set a time you wish:

```
GregorianCalendar later = new GregorianCalendar();
later.set(Calendar.DAY, 23);
later.set(Calendar.HOUR, 2);
```

Hope this helps.

You should look at J[oda Time API](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) for all your date and time requirements. :)

Answer (score 2):

[Use a fake system clock](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=234). Example from this page:

```
public interface TimeSource {
  /** Return the system time. */  
  long currentTimeMillis();
}
```

A simple test implementation might look like this:

```
public final class TestSource implements TimeSource {

  private final AtomicLong curTime = new AtomicLong();

  public long currentTimeMillis() {
    return curTime.incrementAndGet();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to write your own method to get the time/date.

```
long offset = 0;

public long currentTimeMillis() {
    return System.currentTimeMillis() + offset;
}

public void setOffset(long offset) {
    this.offset = offset;
}
```

If you want this to be a singleton or a utility class I suggest you use an `enum`